# Corporate bond quote convention

Tags: fixed-income, quote

I'm not a quant practitioner, but a student so this may be a very simple question.

I was of the understanding corporate US bonds were quoted 1/8 increments and US treasuries in 1/32 increments. Such that a quote of 99 1/8 represents 99.125%.

I came across some study notes, from a fairly reputable source that equated a Nominal 3 5/8 bond to a yield of 3.275% (but 5/8 = 0.625) and a TIPS which was quoted as 1 7/8 to a yield of 1.237% (7/8 = .875)

... am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion is certainly coming from a distinction between **Price** and **Yield**.

1 - You're definitely right in regards to ***Bond Price*** `as 99 1/8 = 99.125`. Likewise `99 1/32 = 99.0313` (*assuming 100 PAR*). It's worth highlighting on the fact that this convention is **only** applicable to US bond prices, as far as I am concerned.

2 - By contrast, ***Bond Yield***  is the *discount rate* at which the present value of all future cash flows from the bond (*coupons and principal included*) is equal to its price (see the below).

[image]

*Where:*

```
 P = Bond price (Clean)
 C = Coupon payments, derived from Coupon frequency as well as Coupon Rate
 F = Face value of the bond
 t = Time to maturity
```

- For simplicity purposes, let's assume a *flat term structure of interest rates*, thus `r` is *constant*.
- Refer to *Excel* **YIELD()** or *Matlab* **YLDMAT()** functions to sort `r` out from the above equation (excluding *day count convention* for simplicity purposes.)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

US bond prices are routinely quoted at much finer intervals. For example, you may see a quote of 99-103, which translates into $99+10/32 + 3/256$.

Further, although there may be a minimum tick size for "prices," so such constraints are imposed on "yields" (at least in the US). In fact, yields are frequently computed up to 15-20 decimal places.